# Gruntfile.js to NPM Scripts

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

as NPM comes more and more popular as Build-Tool and can replace Grunt and Gulp. (as it could do from the beginning) i want to go with it.

But the rare info i can find on this topic is still a little confusing for me.

As i learn better with examples my question would be:

Can anybody provide me the replacement of for example this Gruntfile.js?

I think it could help people a lot in the future.
And also the package.json if changes are needed.
Plus the terminal commands as i think it is needed more or something else then just `grunt watch`

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'build/css/style.css' : 'src/scss/combined.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            options: {
                optimizationLevel: 3
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,// Enable dynamic expansion
                cwd: 'assets/img/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'build/img/'
            }]
        }
    },
    concat: {
        vendorJs: {
            src: ['src/js/vendor/*.js'],
            dest: 'src/js/vendor.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        js: {
            files: {
                'build/js/main.min.js': ['src/js/main.js']
            }
        },
        vendorJs: {
            files: {
                'build/js/vendor.min.js': ['src/js/vendor.js']
            }
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        minify: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src/scss/',
            src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
            dest: 'build/css/',
            ext: '.min.css'
        }
    },
    jshint: {
        beforeconcat: ['src/js/main.js'],
        afterconcat: ['build/js/main.min.js']
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass','cssmin']
        },
        js : {
            files : 'src/js/**/*.js',
            tasks : ['concat','uglify']
        },
        images: {
            files: ['assets/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
            tasks: ['imagemin'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', []);

};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "project_name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "your name",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.7.4",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
        "matchdep": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Take each of your grunt tasks, go to the docs for each app and see what the commandline usage is. Then add that to package.json. Have you done any?

Comment: Ok - this is not very helpful as i have no clue about how to init the scripts and all the "playing together" of the tasks watch etc. i mean sure i can just go through the docs and gather all the knowledge by myself. but i love stackoverflow because people sharing their knowledge.

Comment: You have seven tasks. Pick one and see how far you get. If you get stuck, post a question about that. This question comes off as "Do ALL my work for me". Someone may help, but I doubt it.

Comment: Googled `use npm instead of grunt` - Top 3 results - http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/ http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/why-we-should-stop-using-grunt/ http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-to-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Comment: yeah smart one.. i googled that of course by myself. and as i said in my question everything i find is still a little confusing. and yes i know this would be a lot to just do it. but maybe anybody has did it already and want to share this work. that is why i wrote "FOR EXAMPLE" this Gruntfile. The post are just not clear about how to migrate and stuff. maybe only for me.